# Multiple dependencies with Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Can anyone advice me how can I inject multiple dependencies for a same bean in the spring framework?
I will try to explain the scenario very briefly, in case anyone can suggest me a better solution.

I have a data repository and it has to go through certain filters to filter out unwanted data. The criteria for filtering change and are not fixed to one filter. So, I created a filter handler which filters data based on filters. I want to use IoC and inject the filter dependencies. Its straight forward till here, only that there can be multiple filters. How do I inject multiple dependencies. If I can create a List of filters, how do I declare a list in the xml file?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this (filter1 and filter2 are ids of beans defined elsewhere):

```
<property name="propertyName">
  <list>
    <ref bean="filter1"/>
    <ref bean="filter2"/>
  </list>
</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your filters all implement the same interface, the most elegant way (in my opinion) is like this:

```
@Autowired
private List<YourFilterInterface> filters;
```

This will wire a list containing all registered beans implementing YourFilterInterface. It's available in Spring version 2.5 and up.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-list) tell you how to create a list.

Example taken from above link...

```
<!-- creates a java.util.List instance with the supplied values -->
<util:list id="emails">
    <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
    <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
    <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
    <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
</util:list>
```